# Does Mathematica auto update something causes error load old-version model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I've trained a NN model by NetTrain with Mathematica 11.3.0, and I can load the model correctly to predict.

My model is saved by .mx format.

After few months, I cann't load the model correctly.

However, it seems my .mx model@11.3.4[maybe] can not load by verion@11.3.5
,buy my models.mx@11.3.5 can be load by version@11.3.4

My Mathematica Version is always 11.3.0

And I see a Version Number of model————11.3.5, is it related with the problem?
I've tried .mx format, wlnet, wmlf format.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd contact support. https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Technical

Comment: `PacletUpdate["NeuralNetworks"]` should move you from 11.3.4 to 11.3.5 I think, though.

Comment: From the message it would appear that the MX file was saved using a newer version than the one being used to import it. Is that correct?

Comment: @user6014 it works,thanks